# How to overcome exception -- Illegal address in string ``' while sending email in java'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jakarta-mail

Here is my Code:

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
        String emailTo = prop.getProperty("To");
        String emailCC = prop.getProperty("CC");
        String emailBCC = prop.getProperty("BCC")

String[] to = emailTo.trim().split(",");
        String[] cc = emailCC.trim().split(",");
        String[] bcc = emailBCC.trim().split(",");

 --- Note: Value of CC and BCC is blank in properties file
```

**config.properties**

```
To = tarique.khan@test.com
CC =
BCC =
```

-- I tried, *I think this is because of null value of CC and BCC, but how to resolve it. I have no idea.*

**Exception occured :**

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.3.1
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.<init>(InternetAddress.java:68)
    at com.neosoft.reporting.SendEmail.sendMail(SendEmail.java:165)
    at com.neosoft.reporting.SendEmail.execute(SendEmail.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

**sendMail() declaration with parameters passed :**

If value of CC and BCC is blank in properties file, then what should I pass in method.

```
SendEmail.sendMail("testrobot.personiphi@gmail.com", "xxxx", "smtp.gmail.com",
                            "465", "true", "true", true, 
                            javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.class.getCanonicalName(),
                            "false", to, cc, bcc, "Automation Test Report",
                            "Hi \n Here is your test report of current run that was initiated.",
                            path, reportFileName);
}

public  static boolean sendMail(String userName, String passWord, String host, String port,
                String starttls, String auth, boolean debug, String socketFactoryClass,
                String fallback, String[] to, String[] cc, String[] bcc,
                String subject, String text, String attachmentPath, String attachmentName)
```

Comment: only use valid addresses

Comment: Can u update ur question with config.properties file content ?

Comment: Why there is `CC = BCC` ? It doesen't contain value.

Comment: where is CC=BCC??. Both values are blank in properties file.

Comment: Check value of `prop.getProperty("CC");`. Add `null` check for all key which doesn't have any value.

Comment: if the value of cc and bcc is null than what should i pass to method. Plz check updated question.

Comment: Check my answer & fill free to ask me if you find any trouble in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all fetch `CC` & `BCC` from `config.properties` file as you did

```
 String emailTo = prop.getProperty("To");
 String emailCC = prop.getProperty("CC");
 String emailBCC = prop.getProperty("BCC")
```

then check if they are `NULL` like

```
String[] cc;
String[] bcc;
if(emailCC.length() != 0){
    cc = emailCC.trim().split(",");
}else if(emailBCC.length() != 0){
    bcc = emailBCC.trim().split(",");
}
```

When `cc` & `bcc` are `null`, then add below condition in your sendMail():

```
for(int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
    if(!cc[i].isEmpty())
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc[i]));
}
for(int i = 0; i < bcc.length; i++) {
    if(!bcc[i].isEmpty())
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc[i]));
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

While fetching value from properties file it always send NULL value of CC if nothing is there and String[] stored in 0 index. Than same NULL value is added by msg.addRecipient and it throw exception, So I just added if condition in for loop. It resolved issue.

```
for(int i=0;i<cc.length;i++){                   
    if(cc[i].equals("")){
        continue;   
    } else {
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc[i]));
    }       
}
```

Comment: You can use `String.isEmpty()` & optimizes your code. See my updated answer.

Comment: You should accept my answer. Bcoz it gives you hint to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry brother I find solution before u update answer. :)

Comment: But u get solution while discussing with me & after I have added my answer. Being a good person it's your job to accept my answer & not yours (to get points only). Right.

Comment: It was nice discussion. Good Luck!

Answer (score -2):

check properties file for CC and BCC and i guess those are not blank.